# Importing Paypal SDK sample app into my existing project

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, storyboard

I'm having problems to import Paypal SDK sample app into my existing project.

I added Paypal .xcodeproject into my existing project (now i have all the frameworks, etc)

**Compile** = OK.

The Paypal SDK Sample has a Storyboard with 2 Views and i want to connect them into my existing project, for this i added a Button and created a segue to those views. Then I updated my views class with the module Paypal that it successfully recognized, but it did not work and give me **3 errors**: (I already tried to fix them, delete the segue and link again, I have searched for the errors on stackoverflow, etc.. no success)

**1-** `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7f8bd2f98870> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key successView.'`

**2-** `Could not load the "check.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "ru.test.SwiftSideMenu"`

**3-** `Unknown class _TtC25PayPal_iOS_SDK_Sample_App18MainViewController in Interface Builder file.`

I think this problem is a little complex to paste code here, so i will leave the download links to be easier to check:

https://mega.nz/#!4BZ0UZZS!cRfcXl5jvem8v-_Cs7q0jpEFLGtqUA2RKVQ2ADnEjXU

Comment: You shouldn't generally do it that way. The sample project is, well, a sample. It is not something intended to add to your app. You should add only the SDK and use the sample project as a guide on how to use it.

Comment: I understand, but in my case it fits for my needs :)

Comment: So just add the source files from it, not the whole project. Though bear in mind, that the source for the sample app may be distrubuted under different license than the SDK and therefore may be illegal to use in your app.

Comment: I want to use the sample SDK and i have read the license file and its OK. :)